# Doubt about counting in conditional probability problem

Tags: probability

I want to solve the following problem:

A real estate agent has 8 master keys to open several new homes. Only one master key will open any of the houses. If 40% of these are usually left open, what is the probability that the real estate consultant will open any of the houses?

So, we can define the events:

A:The real estate consultant enters the house
B:The house is open
C:The house is closed
D: The key is correct

And note that

$$P(A)=P(B) \cup P(C \cap D)$$
And for the independence

$$P(A)=P(B) \cup P(C) \cap P(D)$$

Note that $P(A)=0.4$ and $P(C)=1-P(A)=0.6$

But my question is how to do the counting to find $P(D)$, this is because it is not specified how many keys the consultant is trying, because for example if it were for three keys the count is easy

$$\frac{\binom{1}{1} \binom{7}{2}}{\binom{8}{3}}$$

Any suggestions?, I'll apreciatte it

Comment: You have several odd things written... $\Pr(A)$ is a number representing a probability.  You do not (*typically*) find the intersection or union *of numbers*.  Further, mixing unions and intersections is ambiguous.  You should never write $X\cup Y\cap Z$ as it is unclear whether you mean $(X\cup Y)\cap Z$ or if you mean $X\cup (Y\cap Z)$ as these are typically unequal.

Comment: I'd like to clarify some ambiguities in the question. "Only one master key will open any of the houses" I take this to mean that there's exactly $1$ key out of $8$ which opens all the houses, and the $7$ others open none of the houses. "If $40$ percent of these houses are usually left open" I take it to mean that there are many houses and each is open or closed with probability $\frac{40}{100} = \frac 25$. Now, I believe the question is : if you select a random house and a random key, what's the probability that the house opens with that key? Is this right?

Comment: To answer your question: I am assuming that this is an issue with the problem statement itself? It doesn't tell us how many keys the estate agent has when he visits the house. I guess he only has one out of the 8 keys, but I am speculating here.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That's right, sorry for the delay in responding.

Comment: @tps Exactly, one of those eight should be the right one.

Comment: I didn't ask how many are right keys. I asked how many does the estate agent have when he visits the house (ie. how many keys can he try).
If you can confirm that he only has one key and he only tries on one key, that's great (although your problem doesn't say so). If this is the case then the problem is straight forward. You have indicated the logic yourself. What is your difficulty with the problem?